# LINQ, how to select distinct with two columns

Tags: c#, linq

In the following, select query, I need to display distinct values but since I am displaying DataText Field as one value and selectable is DataValue, how could I get distinct.

So I want to display every part in my select list which has a value in subfield but subfields have duplicates values in many part records, So I would like to display a part which has a subfield but where a part has duplicate subfield then I would not display that part. It doesnt matter which part is excluded when its subfield is duplicate

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> pList = (from p in db.Part
                     where (p.field != null || p.field!= "")
                     select p).Distinct().OrderByDescending(l => l.ID).ToArray().Select(x => new SelectListItem


         {
                 Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                 Text = x.subfield
                 });

            ivm.Ids= pList;




<div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent"><a id="\\" href=''>
                @Html.Label("Part Number ")</a> </span><span class="rightContent">
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedPNos, Model.IDs, new { id = "partIdLst", name = "listbox", @class = "chosen-select", multiple = "multiple", data_placeholder = "Click here to Select Part Number", style = "width:90%;", tabindex = "5" })
                </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: how? isn't this linq to sql or EF ?

Comment: @Selman22 I was referring to his comment about the logical, for the distinct issue, I am trying your solution

Comment: no I mean string.IsNullOrEmpty shouldn't be supported how does it even work?

Comment: and you are correct, In EF !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.field) will not work in my specific query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand you want to distinct records by `subfield`. If so, you can do that using `GroupBy`:

```
var pList = db.Part.Where(p => p.field != null && p.field!= "")
             .OrderByDescending(l => l.ID)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(x => x.subfield)
             .Select(x => x.First())
             .Select(x => new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                 Text = x.subfield
             });
```

Or if you can use a third party library I recommend [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method

```
 var pList = db.Part.Where(p => p.field != null && p.field!= "")
             .OrderByDescending(l => l.ID)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .DistinctBy(x => x.subfield)
             .Select(x => new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                 Text = x.subfield
             });
```

I optimized your code a bit by changing `ToArray` with `AsEnumerable`, if you just want to fetch result you can use `AsEnumerable`, it will execute the query and enumerate the results, you don't need to put the result into a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that @Selman Genc gave was helpful but for me it didn't work exactly like that. I had to split it in two parts. So I did it like this...

```
var pList = db.Part.Where(p => p.field != null && p.field!= "")
         .OrderByDescending(l => l.ID)
         .GroupBy(x => x.subfield).ToList();

var finalList = pList.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
         .Select(x => new SelectListItem
         {
             Value = x.ID.ToString(),
             Text = x.subfield
         }).ToList();
```

I don't why it wouldn't work in single line and It wouldn't work with First() either. I was getting an exception and I had to user **FirstOrDefault()**. I had 61 records but in Distinct I should get 24. If I used the **.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())** right after .**Group()**, I was still getting 61 records. But after i split it in two parts it worked.